# Changing the landing site based on season (PHP)

Tags: php, date

So we're trying to create a website that changes the landing page based on off/on season for a festival.
I've gotten my snippet of code to work in a demo, but it seems that the routing won't accept my variable, or anything else than a string like this:

```
'views/mainpage.php'
```

Any ideas as to why it doesn't work?

```
<?php
// Locate the file
$landing = array(
                  "on-season" => "mainpage.php",
                  "off-season" => "sacreddecade.php",
                );

// What is today's date - number
$day = date("z");

//  Days of season
$season_starts = date("z", strtotime("August 01"));
$season_ends   = date("z", strtotime("September 30"));

//  If test to see if it's season
if( $day >= $season_starts && $day <= $season_ends ) {
  $season = "on-season";
  } else {
    $season = "off-season";
  };

$file_path = $landing[$season];
//

$router = new Router(new Request);

$router->get('/', function() {
   include_once("views/$file_path"); //<-- Change this to be root page instead of the login page...
});
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: file_path in C:\laragon\www\web3\index.php on line 33

Warning: include_once(C:\laragon\www\web3\views): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\laragon\www\web3\index.php on line 33

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'views/' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:/laragon/etc/php/pear') in C:\laragon\www\web3\index.php on line 33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$file_path` is not visible in the scope of that anonymous function, try declaring it as

```
$router->get('/', function() use($file_path) { 
    include_once("views/$file_path"); //<-- Change this to be root page instead of the login page...
});
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php